# Regex to spilt the given string

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string `"D:\TFS\Portal\BusinessNotes\104668Desert.jpg"`.and i want to use regex method to get the word `"Desert.jpg"` only.i tried

```
 string[] lines = Regex.Split("D:\TFS\Portal\BusinessNotes\104668Desert.jpg", "[0-9]*");
```

but no use.I want to get "Desert.jpg" in  lines[1].How can i accomplish it.
ps:the numbers may keep change in length

Comment: can you give me an example of valid and invalids input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that without REGEX like:

```
string filePath = @"D:\TFS\Portal\BusinessNotes\104668Desert.jpg";
string result = new String(Path.GetFileName(filePath)
                            .Where(r=> !char.IsDigit(r))
                            .ToArray());
```

Or if you want to do it through REGEX then:

```
string result = Regex.Replace(Path.GetFileName(filePath), @"[\d-]", string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 3):

What you have is a path and you can use [Path.GetFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Path.GetFileName(@"D:\TFS\Portal\BusinessNotes\104668Desert.jpg");

---
```

Edit: then you can strip out the numbers

```
 var newName = string.Join(string.Empty, Path.GetFileName(pathFromAboveExample)
                                             .ToCharArray()
                                              .Where(c => !char.IsNumber(c)));
```

Comment: it returns 104668Desert.jpg that isn't what the OP wants

Comment: @Sayse, now you need a `Where` instead of `Select` otherwise the result would be `true` and `false`. Also you don't need `ToCharArray`

Comment: @Habib - Thanks again :) (My day job uses a language where Select does what c# where does so I get them mixed up alot :))

Comment: @Sayse, this still doesn't compile `IsNumber` is a static method on `char` so it should be `char.IsNumber(x)`, also `string.Join` expects two parameters, delimiter is missing.

Comment: @Habib - Thanks again, I've now tested this and all works well

Answer (score 0):

There may some more efficient ways to do it, but the following will return the filename and extension without the leading numbers:

```
Regex.Match(@"D:\TFS\Portal\BusinessNotes\104668Desert.jpg",
            @"\\[0-9]+([a-zA-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]+)$").Groups[1].Value
```

The regex translates to:

- find a backslash: \
- followed by numbers (1 or more): [0-9]+
- and capture the group: (

  - that contains letters: [a-zA-Z]+
  - then a dot: .
  - then letters: [a-zA-Z]+
- end the capture )
- it must be at the end of the line: $

You can optimize the regex some more, but I wanted to show what was going on.

If you decide to split, you will have to take the second result, since the first and third ones are empty